# I have a legacy C++ project that uses motif for GUI. I want to create a Visual Studio solution of this project. Is this possible?

Tags: visual-studio, motif

I have a legacy C++ project that uses motif for GUI. I want to create a Visual Studio solution of this project. So that I can build/run/debug from Visual studio. Currently I am on a windows box. I ssh into a Unix box and use cc to build and dbx to debug. When I run the application I change my display to the windows box and use xming for the xwindows display.

Is it even possible to build/run/debug from Visual Studio with this setup?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a Motif implementation for Windows and I would expect that to be quite hard to do, given that Motif has been intimately tied to X-Windows for decades.

I assume that you want to use Visual Studio as it is a friendlier environment? In that case, you may want to look into getting better tools on Unix to make your development experience more pleasant. There are various IDEs (if that's your poison) available on Unix, starting with the ubiquitous Eclipse to things like SunStudio (if you're on SUN) and of course all the integration tools that allow you to use the more powerful Unix editors like Emacs or VIM.

If your server connection is slow/flaky/expensive etc and you'd rather develop on your desktop, why not stick a VM with a Linux version or if you're developing for Solaris, one of the OpenSolaris or Solaris 11 developer preview builds into a VM on your machine and work on that one?